# Understanding flex: wrap with align-items: stretch

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If you run the below snippet you can see the `height` of both rows in `flexbox` `container` is different. Can someone explain this?

If you comment **Line A** (= removing explicit `height` from a `flexbox` item) both rows become equal in `height`. I don't understand why?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/5u4zmgb3/) is a JSfiddle of the same snippet, if that is convenient.

```css
*{
  color: blue;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.box1 {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.box2 {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.box3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;/*Line A: comment this and both rows will have same height*/
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 160px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box1">.box1</div>
    <div class="box2">.box2</div>
    <div class="box3">.box3</div>
    <div class="box1">.box1</div>
    <div class="box2">.box2</div>
</div>
```

**My understanding:**

I couldn't find any detailed explanation of `flex-wrap: wrap`. Sites such as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) and [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) just say that when the `wrap` is applied items will have `width = flex-basis` and when one `row` is done with items, items will move on to next flexbox **`row`**. But What will be the alignment of these `row`s within the `flexbox` `container`?

My understanding is: (Assuming `flex-direction: row` and wrapping is permitted) If items are occupying more than one `row`, each `row` will have equal height (`= flexbox_container_height/row_count`) and each `row` act as a `flexbox` `container`. So if I apply a property `flex-items:center`, items will get centered inside each of these row.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @LGSon, I went through the question but I didnt find anything. This question is in no way related to align-content since there is only one flex line. Could you give me a hint on this?  Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Whether `wrap` is applied or not, `flex-basis` is Flexbox's property for _width_, though `width` can still be used, but will not interact with `flex-grow` and `flex-shink` as `flex-basis` does. When one row is full, and items will move on to next, ´align-content` control its distribution/alignment cross axis (height for row direction). W/o `wrap`, or if only one row of items, `align-items` does. This also answers why when comment line A does what it does. If you read up on the `align-*` properties it might make more sense. Do note though, to explain Flexbox fully is off-topic being too broad.

Comment: I also added one more dupe link, which is a good read, and note, Flexbox can take a while to learn as it has a lot of features.

Comment: And whether one or the other is a dupe is difficult to say, as you question cover over a big chunk of Flexbox.

Comment: This is actually a good question. It raises an issue that hasn't received much attention and, therefore, not easy to figure out. Has nothing to do with `flex-wrap` or even `align-items` / `align-content`. @LGSon

Comment: @Michael_B Which issue would that be? ... and which question does it relates to, as there is more than 1 :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem here is not `flex-wrap` or `align-items` or `align-content` (at least not directly).

The real problem is [**`box-sizing`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

Key point:

```
free space !== length
```

The `box-sizing` property applies to lengths, including `height`, `width` and [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis).

The `box-sizing` property *does not* apply to free space, so it is ignored by `align-items`, `flex-grow`, `justify-content`, `fr` and other properties and functions that manage free space.

---

### `box-sizing`

The `box-sizing` property takes two values:

- `content-box` (default value)
- `border-box`

With `content-box`, any lengths you define *will not* include the padding or borders.

With `border-box`, padding and borders are factored into your length calculations.

Consider those terms when referring to the [CSS Box Model](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html).

[image]

<sup>source: [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html)</sup>

Note that `box-sizing` offers no `padding-box` or `margin-box` values. Margins are always added separately.

---

### Your code

Here's your flex container:

```
.container {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;  
   align-items: stretch; /* default setting */
   width: 160px;
   height: 500px;
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

In your flex items, let's remove `box3` for a moment. That's the item with the defined height of 30px.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;  
  align-items: stretch; /* default setting */  
  width: 160px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box3 { height: 30px; }


.box1 { background-color: gray;   }
.box2 { background-color: orange; }
.box3 { background-color: yellow; }

.container > div {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

* {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box1">box1</div>
    <div class="box2">box2</div>
    <!--<div class="box3">box3</div>-->
    <div class="box1">box1</div>
    <div class="box2">box2</div>
</div>
```

Key observations:

- Both rows are now 250px in height.
- Even though there are 4px in top/bottom borders, and `box-sizing` is at the default `content-box`, the height is still 250px.
- The borders are ignored because the height of the items is set using `align-items: stretch` (a free space, not length, calculation).

Now, instead of using `align-items: stretch`, let's use `height: 50%` for each item:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;  
  /* align-items: stretch; */  
  width: 160px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box3 { height: 30px; }


.box1 { background-color: gray;   }
.box2 { background-color: orange; }
.box3 { background-color: yellow; }

.container > div {
  height: 50%; /* NEW */
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

* {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box1">box1</div>
    <div class="box2">box2</div>
    <!--<div class="box3">box3</div>-->
    <div class="box1">box1</div>
    <div class="box2">box2</div>
</div>
```

The height of each item (and row) is now 252px. The top and bottom borders have been added.

If we add `box-sizing: border-box`, then we're back to 250px, just like with `align-items: stretch`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;  
  /* align-items: stretch; */  
  width: 160px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box3 { height: 30px; }


.box1 { background-color: gray;   }
.box2 { background-color: orange; }
.box3 { background-color: yellow; }

.container > div {
  box-sizing: border-box;  /* NEW */
  height: 50%;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

* {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box1">box1</div>
    <div class="box2">box2</div>
    <!--<div class="box3">box3</div>-->
    <div class="box1">box1</div>
    <div class="box2">box2</div>
</div>
```

---

### `.box3`

Now let's re-introduce `.box3` to the HTML structure, restore `box-sizing: content-box` and `align-items: stretch`, and remove `height: 50%` on the items. We're back to the original layout.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;  
  align-items: stretch; 
  width: 160px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box3 { height: 30px; }


.box1 { background-color: gray;   }
.box2 { background-color: orange; }
.box3 { background-color: yellow; }

.container > div {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

* {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box1">box1</div>
    <div class="box2">box2</div>
    <div class="box3">box3</div>
    <div class="box1">box1</div>
    <div class="box2">box2</div>
</div>
```

The `align-items: stretch` items on the first row are 252px in height.

The `align-items: stretch` items on the second row are 248px in height.

This is because `box3` has an actual length defined (`height: 30px`), which activates `box-sizing: content-box`, which adds the top and bottom borders (2px) to the row height (252px).

So let's just apply `box-sizing: border-box` to `box3`.

Sounds right, except `align-items` doesn't care about `box-sizing`.

So although `box-sizing` does make the first row 250px, the borders are still counted in the second row (248px).

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;  
  align-items: stretch; 
  width: 160px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box3 { height: 30px; }


.box1 { background-color: gray;   }
.box2 { background-color: orange; }
.box3 { background-color: yellow; }

.container > div {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* new */
  color: blue;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box1">box1</div>
    <div class="box2">box2</div>
    <div class="box3">box3</div>
    <div class="box1">box1</div>
    <div class="box2">box2</div>
</div>
```

Note that in addition to `padding` and `borders`, there are also issues relating to `line-height` and `font-size` in this particular layout. In order for the row heights to clearly make sense, you would have to remove those factors.

```css
* {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;  
  width: 160px;
  height: 500px;
}

.box3 { height: 30px; }

.box1 { background-color: gray;   }
.box2 { background-color: orange; }
.box3 { background-color: yellow; }

.container > div { flex: 0 0 50px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1">box1</div>
  <div class="box2">box2</div>
  <div class="box3">box3</div>
  <div class="box1">box1</div>
  <div class="box2">box2</div>
</div>
```

Now the items in the first row are 265px in height, and the ones in the second row are 235px in height.

Free space is what's left over after all fixed lengths have been factored into the calculation.

```
500 - 30 = 470 ----> this is the free vertical space in your container

470 / 2 = 235  ----> this is the free space allocated to each row

235 + 30 = 265  ----> this is the height of the first row, since 30px is added to the free space
```

Comment: I completely misunderstood/misread OP's _"...the height of both rows in flexbox container is different."_. Great, upvoted...and can't see how this isn't more or less spot on :)

Comment: Up until the last snippet, your explanation was based on box-sizing. I would say I got you 80%. But in the last snippet last sentence, I totally lost you: *It then factors in the 30px fixed height by adding 15px of free space to row one and removing 15px from row two.*. What is the reason behind doing so? Can you refer to docs which explain this behavior of taking h/2 from another row? Good lord. Now I am more confused than I was when I asked the question.

Comment: Sorry. I should have been more clear and specific. Read that section again now. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Thanks for your last edit. I am sure there are many other details with this behaviour. Can you refer some docs, explaining this behaviour? That would help a lot.

Comment: Free space (in flex and grid CSS) is generally the space left over after all other lengths have been established. If you want to get really specific and study the algorithm, here it is: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#resolve-flexible-lengths

Comment: Thanks for you the time and effort you put @Michael_B. I really grateful for this. I am learning CSS in theory. Hope I would contribute it back the same way.

Answer (score -3):

You are giving height of 500px to container and height of 30px to box3 which is a child element of container.

You should give equal height value to parent child relationship or just dont give any height to let them take their own equal heights.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer my question. What you are telling, I have already mentioned in my question.  I have explicitly asked: *Can someone explain this?*. I am looking for the explanation on **why is it happening**, not the workaround.